# Обратная лесенка в Python

Tags: python

Только начинаю изучать Python. Сделала задание: "По данному натуральному n ≤ 9 выведите лесенку из n ступенек, i-я ступенька состоит из чисел от 1 до i без пробелов".
Код:

```
n=int(input())
y=''
for i in range(1, n+1):
    y=y+str(i)
    print(y)
```

Как изменить код, чтобы лесенка была в обратном направлении? Например:

```
1234
123
12
1
```

Comment: `range` может принимать три параметра `start`, `stop`, `step` - начало, окончание и шаг. Настрой таким образом, что бы выдавал нужную тебе последовательность

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К примеру, использовать цикл с обратным шагом, а в нем вложенный цикл:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        print(j, end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
n = int(input())
y = ''

for i in range(1, n+1):
    y = y + str(i)
    print(y)

print()
_list = [ str(i) for i in range(1, n+1) ]
for i in range(n): 
    print(''.join(_list[:n-i]))

print()    
_list = [ str(i) for i in range(n, 0, -1) ]
for i in range(n): 
    print(''.join(_list[:n-i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(7)
y=''
for i in range(1, n+1):
    y=y+str(i)
    print(y[::-1])
```

[:: - 1] - отображает данные наоборот

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = int(input())
ladder = ''.join([str(x) for x in range(1, n + 1)])
while n > 0:
    print(ladder)
    ladder = ladder[:-1]
    n -= 1
```